# create postgres db with owner and connection limit in one line?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a db in postgres with an owner and simultaneously impose a connection limit.

Currently I have:

```
CREATE DATABASE <db> WITH OWNER = <owner>;
ALTER DATABASE <db> CONNECTION LIMIT 1;
```

Is there any way to make that a one-liner? I tried it with multiple `with`s but got syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

```
CREATE DATABASE <db> 
   WITH 
     OWNER = <owner>
     CONNECTION LIMIT 1;
```

(The `with` is optional, but if provided, you only need it once)